# Type of 'this' in abstract class and overloaded method resolution order confusion

Tags: c#, java, overloading, method-resolution-order

This very simple example confuses me:

```
public class X {
    public void XMethod(A a) {
        Console.WriteLine(a.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("Got A");
    }

    public void XMethod(B b) {
        Console.WriteLine(b.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("Got B");
    }
}

public abstract class A {
    public virtual void M(X x) {
        Console.WriteLine(this.GetType());
        x.XMethod(this);
    }
}

public class B : A {

}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        X x = new X();
        B b = new B();
        b.M(x);
    }
}
```

Output of this is

```
B
B
Got A
```

Everything up until 'Got A' is fine. I would expect that method `X.XMethod(B)` would be called when I invoke method `M` on instance of class `B`.

What is going on here? Why is `XMethod(A)` called, and not `XMethod(B)`, when it is clear that type of provided argument is `B` and not `A`?

PS: I got same output in java for equivalent implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is only on `A.M` method**. Not one for `A` and one for `B`.

The IL is the same, in `A.M`, for all instances; at compile-time, `A.M` only knows `this` to be `A` (or `object`), hence it resolves **always** to `XMethod(A)`. This method resolution is in the IL generated at compile-time, and doesn't change for subclasses (indeed, the subclass could be in a separate assembly that the compiler doesn't even know about):

```
.method public hidebysig newslot virtual instance void M(class X x) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: call instance class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Object::GetType()
    L_0006: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(object)
    L_000b: ldarg.1 
    L_000c: ldarg.0 
    L_000d: callvirt instance void X::XMethod(class A)
    L_0012: ret 
}
```

To get the behaviour you want, you *could* use `dynamic`. Not saying you *should*, though.

Comment: Thanks. I am using dynamic, but in other parts of project and I don't like idea to use it here. I solved this by override-ing method in subclasses (witch is what I wanted to avoid, because there is ~15 classes that contain same method now).

Comment: Btw, I still think that this is some kind of very old language design bug... Or maybe I am just used to dynamic laguages more then I thought.

Comment: @del-boy no, this is not a language bug at all. This would be identical in any static-typed compiler, including Java, C++, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is always refer to the current object which is invoking the operation...in you case if you want to call the B method you need to override the virtual operation because if you are not overriding it refering to the method parent class only..

```
public class B : A {  
public override void M(X x) {
         Console.WriteLine(this.GetType());
         x.XMethod(this);
     } 
}
```

Comment: This is what I did after I realised that first approach doesn't work, but I was curious why is it happening. Override-ing is problematic because now I have ~15 classes with same method in them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% shure, but I think when using method overloading with two possible type matches always the "lowest one" is used.

EDIT: After hvd's comment I checked it and he is right:
E.g. the following example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "bla";
    object obj = str;

    DoIt(str);
    DoIt(obj);
}

public static void DoIt(object p) { Console.WriteLine("Object!"); }
public static void DoIt(string p) { Console.WriteLine("String!"); }
```

prints

> String!
>   Object!

Comment: That's not how it works. If you try `x.XMethod((B)this)`, the `XMethod(A)` overload is still the "lowest one", but the `B` overload will be chosen.